# How to get my VBA scraper to find the above row?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have some experience with VBA but I am very new to web scraping with VBA. However I am very enthusiastic about it and thought of a 1000 ways how could I use it and make my job easier. :)

My problem is that I have a website with two input fields and one button. I can write in the input fields (they have ID so I can easily find them)
My code for the input fields:

```
.Document.getElementById("header_keyword").Value = my_first
.Document.getElementById("header_location").Value = my_last
```

But I am really stuck with clicking the button.

Here is the html code for the buttons:

```
<span class="p2_button_outer p2_button_outer_big"><input class="p2_button_inner" type="submit" value="Keresés" /></span>
<span class="p2_button_outer p2_button_outer_big light hide_floating"><a id="tour_det_search" class="p2_button_inner" href="http://www.profession.hu/kereses">Részletes keresés</a></span>
```

As you can see there are two different buttons near each other, and they share the same class. I am looking for the first/upper one. My problem is that it has no ID, only class, type and value. But I was not able to find getelementsbytype or getelementsbyvalue method. 
Is there any solution to find the button by type or value (or both)?

Sorry if I am asking something stupid but as I said previously I am new in scraping...:)
Thank you in advance and have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function. It looks for a first HTML element with the given caption. You can also limit the searching by HTML tag.
(The code is compatible with IE <9 that doesn't contain `getElementsByClassName` method).

```
Public Function FindElementByCaption(dom As Object, Caption As String, _
                    Optional Tag As String, Optional Nested As Boolean = True) As Object
    Dim ControlsSet As Variant
    Dim Controls As Variant
    Dim Control As Object
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    Set ControlsSet = VBA.IIf(Nested, dom.all, dom.childNodes)


    If VBA.Len(Tag) Then
        Set Controls = ControlsSet.tags(VBA.LCase(Tag))
    Else
        Set Controls = ControlsSet
    End If


    For Each Control In Controls
        If VBA.StrComp(Control.InnerHtml, Caption, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set FindElementByCaption = Control
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Control

End Function
```

Here is how to apply it in your code:

```
Dim button As Object
Set button = FindElementByCaption(.Document, "Keresés", "INPUT", True)

If Not button Is Nothing Then
    Call button.Click
Else
    Call MsgBox("Button has not been found")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Fortunatelly I have worked out the solution. :)

What I did is the following. I made searched for the relevant classes and then using the getAttribute() method and looping thru the classes I searched for the specific value and clicked on it when found it.

Below is the working code:

```
Set my_classes = .Document.getElementsByClassName("p2_button_inner")

For Each class In my_classes
    If class.getAttribute("value") = "Keresés" Then
        Range("c4") = "Clicked"
        class.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next class
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**CSS selector:**

Use a CSS selector to target the element of:

```
input[value='Keresés']
```

This says element with `input` tag, having attribute `value` with value `'Keresés'`.

---

**CSS query:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA:**

You apply the selector via the `querySelector` method of `document`.

```
ie.document.querySelector("input[value='Keresés']").Click
```